# How do I create a WP8 Live Tile with a custom layout?

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

I'm looking to create a Live Tile which is similar to the Iconic tile but allows me to use a custom Count value (i.e. non-integer string).

The closest I've come is that I must create the contents using a bitmap and then use that image as the tile. Unfortunately I don't know how this is commonly done.

I'm looking to create tiles similar to the one that's described in this question (though this question is orthogonal to my issue): [Custom live tile rendering issue on Windows Phone (7/8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229966/custom-live-tile-rendering-issue-on-windows-phone-7-8)

In short,

- Is WriteableBitmap the best way of creating Live Tile layouts?
- Is there a mechanism by which I can convert XAML into the Live Tile?

An example of the layout I'd like to achieve is somewhat displayed in the Skype Live Tile seen [here](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC600903.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, creating a custom bitmap is the way to go. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557183/drawing-a-wpf-usercontrol-with-databinding-to-an-image) along with [this article](http://www.jayway.com/2012/04/03/advanced-transparent-live-tiles-with-count-for-windows-phone/) to be very helpful when I was doing my live tiles.

If you don't mind purchasing third-party controls you can check out Telerik's LiveTileHelper control (if you're a member of Nokia's developer program you already have access to this).

For my first app I opted to roll my own solution based on the first two links. I have a base class that handles the work of taking a `FrameworkElement` (each derived class is responsible for generating the `FrameworkElement` that contains the information to render) and creating the corresponding `WritableBitmap` instance which I then save as a .PNG using the ToolStack C# PNG Writer Library.

As an example, here's my code to generate the control that represents a small pinned secondary tile in one of my apps:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the fully populated and initialized control that displays
    /// the information that should be included in the tile image.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// We manually create the control in code instead of using a user control
    /// to avoid having to use the XAML parser when we do this work in our
    /// background agent.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <returns>
    /// The fully populated and initialized control that displays
    /// the information that should be included in the tile image.
    /// </returns>
    protected override FrameworkElement GetPopulatedTileImageControl()
    {
        var layoutRoot = new Grid()
                            {
                                Background          = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush( System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) ),
                                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                                VerticalAlignment   = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
                                Height              = TileSize.Height,
                                Width               = TileSize.Width,
                                Margin              = new Thickness( 0, 12, 0, 0 )
                            };
        var stopName = new TextBlock()
                            {
                                Text                = Stop.Description,
                                TextTrimming        = TextTrimming.WordEllipsis,
                                TextWrapping        = TextWrapping.Wrap,
                                Margin              = new Thickness( 7, 0, 7, 12 ),
                                MaxHeight           = 135,
                                Width               = TileSize.Width - 14,
                                VerticalAlignment   = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
                                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                                FontFamily          = (System.Windows.Media.FontFamily) Application.Current.Resources[ "PhoneFontFamilySemiBold" ],
                                FontSize            = (double) Application.Current.Resources[ "PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge" ],
                                Style               = (Style) Application.Current.Resources[ "PhoneTextNormalStyle" ]
                            };

        Grid.SetColumn( stopName, 0 );
        Grid.SetRow( stopName, 0 );

        layoutRoot.Children.Add( stopName );
        return layoutRoot;
    }
```

This is a super-simple control with just a `TextBlock`, but you can easily expand on this. Note that I don't use a `UserControl` here as I also run this code in a background agent where you have significant memory constraints.

Once I have a control I generate a `WritableBitmap` like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Renders the tile image to a <see cref="WritableBitmap"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="WritableBitmap"/> instance that contains the rendered
    /// tile image.
    /// </returns>
    private WriteableBitmap RenderTileImage()
    {
        var tileControl = GetPopulatedTileImageControl();
        var controlSize = new Size( TileSize.Width, TileSize.Height );
        var tileImage   = new WriteableBitmap( (int) TileSize.Width, (int) TileSize.Height );

        // The control we're rendering must never be smaller than the tile
        // we're generating.
        tileControl.MinHeight   = TileSize.Height;
        tileControl.MinWidth    = TileSize.Width;

        // Force layout to take place.
        tileControl.UpdateLayout();
        tileControl.Measure( TileSize );
        tileControl.Arrange( new Rect( new Point( 0, 0 ), TileSize ) );
        tileControl.UpdateLayout();

        tileImage.Render( tileControl, null );
        tileImage.Invalidate();

        tileControl = null;
        GC.Collect( 2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true );

        // Adjust the rendered bitmap to handle the alpha channel better.
        CompensateForRender( tileImage );

        return tileImage;
    }
```

Again, I'm making explicit calls to `GC.Collect` to help keep my memory consumption under control when running this code as part of my background agent. The `CompensateForRender` method is based on the code in the linked article.

Hope this helps.