# Drawing a Custom Bitmap in Windows Universal App?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bitmap, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm trying to draw a custom Live Tile in my Windows Universal App.  Specifically, a circle.  I understand that I can provide a bitmap, but I'm not having any luck.

I've tried to follow examples online, but without any luck.  Like this: [How do I create a WP8 Live Tile with a custom layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258758/how-do-i-create-a-wp8-live-tile-with-a-custom-layout)

It uses a WriteableBitmap's .Render() - but when I try to do the same, it seems that .Render() does not exist.

Can someone give me an example of how to create a bitmap that will work in a Universal App that will run on Windows Phone 8 (and ideally the Windows 8 + Windows 10 + Windows Phone 10)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then RenderTargetBitmap is the new class you are looking for. This is supported by Universal apps and supports the rendering of UI elements.